# Is there an Android EditView for editing email content like the Gmail app does?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, webview

I have an app that needs to provide an email client, so I need a View that shows email content and allows the user to edit that content - just like the Gmail app allows you to view and edit email content.

I can use WebView to show the email content (which looks acceptable but not great), however it doesn't allow you to edit the content (at least I haven't been able to figure out how).

I tried to use EditText with `HtmlCompat.fromHtml()` to apply basic formatting and images. However, this just can't handle important HTML tags like tables.

I know that this can be done since Gmail and other email clients do it - what is the secret sauce or library?

Comment: if you want to work with Native Android Apps, You can use RecyclerView to load and  manage Your Emails content using JSON data from your API.

Answer (score 2):

```
implementation 'com.github.bxute:MarkDEditor:v0.16'
```

Use this github library, will solve your issue

Comment: Really looking for an editor that can handle the vagaries of HTML emails, rather than mark down. The client has to handle emails sent from other email source.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with Native Android Apps, You can use RecyclerView to load and manage Your Email content using JSON data from your API.

Or you can try this Open Source project from GitHub

1. [FairEmail](https://github.com/M66B/FairEmail)
2. [k9mail](https://github.com/k9mail/k-9)
3. [mailbox-app](https://github.com/RobinCheptileh/mailbox-app)
4. [Simple-email-app](https://github.com/JosiasSena/Simple-email-app)
5. [BlitzMail](https://github.com/grote/BlitzMail)
6. [Android-Email-Client](https://github.com/Criptext/Android-Email-Client)
7. [android-email-client-app](https://github.com/milochen0418/android-email-client-app)

Comment: My only requirement was handling the UI for presenting an existing email (from any source) and being able to modify that for forwarding/replying etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered writing a WYSIWYG editor component for handling edits? This [tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-develop-a-wysiwyg-editor-in-android-just-like-medium-30e0d4c8471f) seems like a good starting point. The [source code](https://github.com/bxute/MarkDEditor) is also available on Github.

Comment: None of the answers seem to satisfy, perhaps I had my hopes too high, however the tutorial reference was probably the most useful of all the answers, so am awarding to you.